# How to add external routes in an OJET application

Tags: oracle-jet

There is a scenario where there is an app written in angular and another app written in Oracle JET running on the same server. The OJET application is required to reuse a few modules from the existing angular application. Is it possible to configure external routes with ojrouter or any other mechanism to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Are you trying to open a page on a new tab by clicking an item on your `<oj-navigation-list>` element?

Comment: You may use iFrame and load the angular piece inside it.